# Meaning of "canonically restricted" in "Conjugation is canonically restricted to bacterial cells as the donor and recipient"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, terminology

From "[Horizontal gene transfer: building the web of life](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v16/n8/full/nrg3962.html)" by Soucy et al., 2015:

> The three most recognized mechanisms of HGT in prokaryotes are conjugation, transformation and 1 transduction (FIG. 1). Conjugation requires physical contact between a donor and a recipient cell via a conjugation pilus, through which genetic material is transferred. Conjugation is **canonically** **restricted** to bacterial cells as the donor and recipient, however, Agrobacterium spp. is an exception and uses its conjugation machinery for HGT into plant cells [14,15]

Just to make sure: does the sentence mean

> Conjugation, **by its canonical definition**, applies only to the transfer of genetic material between bacterial cells. However, Agrobacterium spp. is an exception and uses its conjugation machinery for HGT into plant cells.

I.e., we use the term **conjugation** only in reference to transmission of genes between bacteria, but we do make one exception and call Agrobacterium's injection of genes into plants **conjugation** as well. Am I right?

---

Comment: Wouldn't this be rather a question for geneticists and not learners of English?  Or are you asking on an off-chance of bioengineers hanging out in ELL?

Comment: @VictorBazarov - I thought it was too simple for Biology SE and likely concerned only the use of "canonically restricted" as an English expression. Maybe I'll move it to Bio SE later - if there's no answer here.

Comment: I think *by its canonical definition* is apt, though I'm not sure if it's strictly correct because of the "definition" part. (To me, "definition" implies that we've defined how things are, but I know this is a moot point.) In any case, I'd understand this *[canonically](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/canonical)* in the meaning of "Accepted as being accurate and authoritative" or "According to recognized rules or scientific laws".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your paraphrase, *by its canonical definition*, is certainly plausible, the word *canonical* can also mean "regular, regularized" in the sense of "insignificant variations having been excluded or normalized". I would paraphrase it here loosely as follows:

> *As a rule*, conjugation occurs between bacteria (as both donor and recipient) but there is *an exception* in Agrobacterium, which donates
>   HGT to plant cells.

Comment: I am a Biologist and I am vouching for what you have written! +1 for your answer!